# Each countable Hausdorff space is Katetov KC

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

---

A space $ ( X, \tau )$ is said to be Katetov- KC if there is a topoloy $\sigma \subset \tau$ such that  $(X,\sigma) $ is minimal KC.

***Theorem: Each countable Hausdorff space is Katetov KC***.

**proof**: If $ ( X, \tau )$ is a countable Hausdorff, then  it can be condensed onto a second countable Hausdorff space. Then the result is clear by below theorem.

"Every  sequential KC space is Katetov - KC."

**My question is:**

why "**the countable Hausdorff can be condensed onto a second countable Hausdorff space**" ?

Comment: This is Corollary 2.7 from O.T. Alas, M.G. Tkachenko, V.V. Tkachuk, and R.G. Wilson: [The FDS-property and spaces in which compact sets are closed](http://www.jams.or.jp/scm/contents/e-2004-5/2004-46.pdf). Maryam: When you ask a question here, please, include also the origin of the question. (This is useful for many reasons, for example, it provides further context.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a countable Hausdorff space. Let $[X]^2$ be the set of $2$-element subsets of $X$. For each $\{x,y\}\in[X]^2$ there are $U_x,U_y\in\tau$ such that $x\in U_x$, $y\in U_y$, and $U_x\cap U_y=\varnothing$. Let $$\mathscr{S}=\bigcup_{\{x,y\}\in[X]^2}\{U_x,U_y\}\;;$$ clearly $\mathscr{S}$ is a countable subset of $\tau$. Now take $\mathscr{S}$ as a subbase for a topology $\sigma$ on $X$; $\sigma$ has as a base the set $$\mathscr{B}=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{F}\text{ is a finite subset of }\mathscr{S}\right\}\;,$$ which is countable, so $\sigma$ is second countable, and clearly $\sigma\subseteq\tau$. Finally, for each $\{x,y\}\in[X]^2$ we know that $U_x,U_y\in\sigma$, so $\sigma$ is Hausdorff. That is, $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ can be condensed onto the second countable Hausdorff space $\langle X,\sigma\rangle$.