# second countable Hausdorff space

Tags: real-analysis

EDIT by YC: the body of this question is copied verbatim fom Brian M. Scott's answer to this MSE question [Each countable Hausdorff space is Katetov KC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465534/each-countable-hausdorff-space-is-katetov-kc)

---

> **If (X, τ) is a countable Hausdorff space, then it can be condensed onto a second
>   countable Hausdorff space.**

Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a countable Hausdorff space. Let $[X]^2$ be the set of $2$-element subsets of $X$. For each $\{x,y\}\in[X]^2$ there are $U_x,U_y\in\tau$ such that $x\in U_x$, $y\in U_y$, and $U_x\cap U_y=\varnothing$. Let $$\mathscr{S}=\bigcup_{\{x,y\}\in[X]^2}\{U_x,U_y\}\;;$$  $\mathscr{S}$ is a countable subset of $\tau$. Now take $\mathscr{S}$ as a subbase for a topology $\sigma$ on $X$; $\sigma$ has as a base the set $$\mathscr{B}=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{F}\text{ is a finite subset of }\mathscr{S}\right\}\;,$$ which is countable, so $\sigma$ is second countable, and clearly $\sigma\subseteq\tau$. Finally, for each $\{x,y\}\in[X]^2$ we know that $U_x,U_y\in\sigma$, so $\sigma$ is Hausdorff. That is, $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ can be condensed onto the second countable Hausdorff space $\langle X,\sigma\rangle$.

> I would like to know:
>
> Why is it right: " take $\mathscr{S}$ as a subbase for a topology $\sigma$ on $X$; $\sigma$ **has as a base the set** $$\mathscr{B}=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{F}\text{ is a finite subset of }\mathscr{S}\right\}\;,$$ **which is countable, so $\sigma$ is second countable " ?**

Comment: If you are quoting someone, for instance someone on math.stackexchange, or someone in a paper or book, could you please give the reference or a link?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of the subbase:

> Let $X$ be a topological space with topology $\tau$. A subbase of $\tau$ is usually defined as a subcollection $B$ of $\tau$ such that the collection of open sets consisting of all finite intersections of elements of $B$, together with the set $X$ and the empty set, forms a basis for $\tau$.

This is exactly what he does when defining $\mathscr{B}$.

Also, [the set of finite subsets of a countable set is countable](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_of_Finite_Subsets_of_Countable_Set_is_Countable). So the set $A$ of finite subsets $\mathscr{F}$ is countable and it follows that the set of finite subsets $\bigcap{\mathscr{F}}$ is countable.

Since

> A space is said to be second-countable if its topology has a countable base.

$\sigma$ is second-countable.